# How to move two pictures to a folder? PHP

Tags: image, file, resize, target

I've got this code and I need copy the two images 'original' and 'tmp_image' in folder images/app.

How i can move this pictures? :

I've tried this but only moves picture 'original':

**move_uploaded_file("images/app/".$_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"],"images/app/".$_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);**

```
 function resize($target,$new,$w,$h,$type){
   list($wo,$ho)=getimagesize($target);
    if($type=="image/jpeg"){
     $nen = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }elseif($type=="image/gif"){
     $nen = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    }elseif($type=="image/png"){
     $nen = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    }
      $chen = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
      imagecopyresampled($chen,$nen,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$wo,$ho);
      imagejpeg($chen,$new,80);
                                         }
```

And

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);
    $meter = "http://server/prueba/images/app/" . $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
    $target = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
    $ssql = "insert into ofertas (imagen) values ('" . $meter . "')";
            $new = "resize_".$target;
            $type = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
            $w = 80;
            $h = 80;
            resize($target,$new,$w,$h,$type);
```

Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation of a problem is a bit hard to understand. If I got it right, below is the answer.

If you are moving uploaded file to new location and then resizing it - it is overwritten.
Try changing target name and copy file to target name.
For example

> $target = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];

Change to

```
 $target = 'thumb_'.$_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
```

Comment: Changed and displays errors: Warning: getimagesize(thumb_4.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(thumb_4.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Sorry, didn't thought it through :)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php
Copy first file to $target name